# PowerShell calling environment variable with another variable

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I have an environment values like these

- password_STG
- password_DEV
- passowrd_PROD

so I need to call environment variable from PowerShell like this:

```
 $ENV:$password_environment
```

But this is not working showing below error

```
Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name
character. Consider using ${} to delimit the name.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidVariableReferenceWithDrive
```

Comment: The reference would be `$env:password_environment`, not `$env:$password_environment` (remove the embedded `$`).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart No. They want the environment variable whose *name* is stored in the variable `$password_environment`, not the environment variable `password_environment`.

Comment: That's not clear to me from the question, but glad you understood.

Answer (score 4):

PowerShell makes the environment available as a PSDrive `env:`, so you can use `Get-Item` to get an environment variable by a name stored in another variable:

```
$password_environment = 'password_STG'
(Get-Item env:$password_environment).Value
```